# python3 grpc compiler: how to handle absolute and relative imports in .protos?

Tags: grpc-python, containerd

I'm trying to generate working Python modules from the containerd API .proto files as to be found here: https://github.com/containerd/containerd/tree/master/api.

Unfortunately, containerd's own .proto files contain references such as (in `api/events/container.proto`):

```proto
import weak "github.com/containerd/containerd/protobuf/plugin/fieldpath.proto";
```

Now, this import is actually located in `protobuf/plugin/fieldpath.proto`, as opposed to (`vendor/`)`github.com/containerd/...`. A simple `-I ...` does not work in this context, as the import uses a "github"-absolute path, whereas the corresponding sources aren't located inside the vendor branch.

Simply copying over the sources inside `vendor/github.com/...` will cause runtime errors when trying to use the generated Python modules: this is because there are now two separate instances for the same protocol elements trying to register with GRPC with the same protocol element name, yet from two different Python modules. The GRPC Python runtime thus throws an error and terminates.

How can I correctly get this resolved when using `python3 -m grpc.tools.protoc ...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some trial+error I've finally come up with a working solution that works as follows and which might be helpful for others facing gRPC-based APIs with are more complex than many gRPC examples.

1. copy over the API .proto files into a directory structure that reflects the final desired Python package and module structure. For containerd, this means having everything within a containerd/ directory structure, avoiding github.com/ folders and aliasing (import aliasing will break things).
2. fix all import statement paths that would either cause module aliasing or won't fit with the final desired package structure. A good way to do this is with sed while copying over the proto files. In my case, replace "github.com/containerd/containerd/..." with just "containerd/..." import paths.
3. in case of vendor'ed .proto files somehow related to gRPC infrastructure and where gRPC PyPI packages exist, such as grpcio and protobuf, put then side-by-side with your API .proto files, but do not vendor them into the API directory hierarchy. Ensure to put them in a directory structure that mimics the package structure of the already available PyPI packages.
4. use protoc via the python3 interpreter to generate the Python modules only for your API .proto files; make sure that the supplemental .proto files from grpc and protobuf are includable, but do not create modules for them. protoc does this already correctly unless you vendor the supplemental .proto files into your API .proto files ... so don't do this.
5. make sure that your grpcio and protobuf PyPI packages are recent and somehow in sync, avoid especially totally outdated Debian distro packages, install from PyPI ... even if this is a painfully slow process on arm64 because there are no binary wheels for grpcio and grpciotools. Symptoms when doing not so include runtime errors of missing grpc or protobuf object fields.